# Linux uuidgen - uniqueness of output across VM instances

Tags: linux, random, cloud, uuid

**Background:**
I have developed a software which runs on Linux and I distribute licenses for it to work.
For Linux installations I am using system UUID and my license is based on that.
For installing on various Cloud setups, I am packaging the OS with my software and providing to the User. User deploys it and requests license based on UUIDs shown in my software.

**Issue:**
When User deploys each instance, in few Cloud setups, UUIDs are same for different VM instances on same physical machine.
This causes a problem for license.

**Solution:**
What I have planned to do is simple: when OS boots up first time call uuidgen and generate UUID and store it to a file. After that for next reboot I will take it from this file so UUID will be same for the machine.

**Questions on above solution:**

## 1

uuidgen with random option calculates uuid by utilizing /dev/random
In a VM setup since there is no direct hardware access for generating this random seed, **can /dev/random value possibly be same in different VM instances? which means uuidgen will operate on same seed?**

## 2

**if UUID generated in two different linux systems by uuidgen during first time bootup are same because the random seed was not good enough, then the next UUID generated will also be same in those Linux systems?**
i.e.
While booting up, uuidgen is called and produces a UUID1 in VM1. Say it is same as UUID2 when uuidgen was called in another VM instance VM2.
If uuidgen is called again for next UUID in VM1, will it be again same if called in VM2?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most probable thing to investigate is if the customer has generated those VM images from a common one, in which the uuid has already been generated.  Having the lenght a uuid has, it's most improbable that you produce a colission of uuids.

By the way, requiring your software to depend on the uuid stored in a file allows your customer to clone your VM **after** your software has been installed, and all licenses validated by cloning.

If you want to protect your software licenses on VMs, you'll have to do some connecting to a license server and do some public key signing feature to validate licenses.

The main problem is that two cloned images from a virtual machine are exactly equal (hardware and software) and as so, can run the same software without having any difference from the point in time they where cloned.